# Oat++ server provider not listening on port

Tags: c++, oat++

I am trying to write a wrapper around the Oat++ system to simplify usage across multiple microservices, but, I have run into an issue.

**Aim**

I want to be able to specify the service provider points (address, port and address type of IPV4/IPV6) via a class function.

**Issue**

If I run the minimum viable code below and try to connect to  HTTP:://localhost:8888/test I can't connect to the port (I get a timeout).  If I change the dynamic for loop for the hard-coded provider and try to connect I get the expected 404.

So change:

```
        for (auto entry = m_serviceProviderEntry.begin ();
             entry != m_serviceProviderEntry.end (); entry++)
        {
            auto addrType = (*entry).networkType == SERVICENETWORKTYPE_IPV4 ?
                oatpp::network::Address::IP_4 : oatpp::network::Address::IP_6;
            auto provider = oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider::createShared (
                { (*entry).address, v_uint16 ((*entry).networkPort), addrType });
            m_connectionProviders.push_back (provider);

            oatpp::network::Server server (provider, m_connectionHandler);
            server.run (true);
        }
```

for:

```
auto provider = oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider::createShared (
                { "localhost", 8888, oatpp::network::Address::IP_4 });
oatpp::network::Server server (provider, m_connectionHandler);
server.run (true);
        }
```

Any suggestions or help would be gratefully appreciated as I don't understand why this is failing as it is, maybe use of std::shared_ptr in a std::list?

**Minimal viable and repeatable code**

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include "oatpp/web/server/HttpConnectionHandler.hpp"
#include "oatpp/network/tcp/server/ConnectionProvider.hpp"
#include "oatpp/network/Server.hpp"

enum ServiceNetworkType
{
    SERVICENETWORKTYPE_IPV4,
    SERVICENETWORKTYPE_IPV6
};

struct ServiceProviderEntry
{
    std::string address;
    v_uint16 networkPort;
    ServiceNetworkType networkType;
};

class Example
{
public:
    Example () : m_shutdownRequested (false) { }

    bool Initialise ()
    {
        int iResult;
        WSADATA wsaData;
        iResult = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) return false;

        return true;
    }

    void Execute ()
    {
        m_router = oatpp::web::server::HttpRouter::createShared ();
        m_connectionHandler = oatpp::web::server::HttpConnectionHandler::createShared (m_router);

        for (auto entry = m_serviceProviderEntry.begin ();
             entry != m_serviceProviderEntry.end (); entry++)
        {
            auto addrType = (*entry).networkType == SERVICENETWORKTYPE_IPV4 ?
                oatpp::network::Address::IP_4 : oatpp::network::Address::IP_6;
            auto provider = oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider::createShared (
                { (*entry).address, v_uint16 ((*entry).networkPort), addrType });
            m_connectionProviders.push_back (provider);

            oatpp::network::Server server (provider, m_connectionHandler);
            server.run (true);
        }

        while (!m_shutdownRequested) { }
    }

    void AddServiceProvider (std::string address,
        int networkPort,
        ServiceNetworkType networkType)
    {
        ServiceProviderEntry entry = { address,
                                       v_uint16 (networkPort),
                                       networkType };
        m_serviceProviderEntry.push_back (entry);
    }

private:
    bool m_shutdownRequested;

    std::shared_ptr<oatpp::web::server::HttpRouter> m_router;
    std::shared_ptr<oatpp::web::server::HttpConnectionHandler> m_connectionHandler;
    std::list <std::shared_ptr<oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider>> m_connectionProviders;
    std::list<ServiceProviderEntry> m_serviceProviderEntry;
};

int main ()
{
    auto app = new Example ();
    app->Initialise ();
    app->AddServiceProvider ("localhost", 8888, SERVICENETWORKTYPE_IPV4);
    app->Execute ();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean exactly, you can't connect to the port. Is there any error message? What's happening?

Comment: When I 'hard-code' the provider I get 404, but with code provided I get timeout, e.g. connection failed.

Comment: @infinitezero Modified question as your comment was useful in improving the question., thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
for(...) {
   oatpp::network::Server server (provider, m_connectionHandler); // Server object created
   server.run (true); // Run server accept loop in a separate thread
} // Server object deleted, server accept loop is terminated
```

At the end of each iteration your server object is deleted.
`ConnectionProvider` object is deleted too.

Possible solution would look something like the following:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<oatpp::network::Server>> servers;
for(...) {
  ...
  auto server = std::make_shared<oatpp::network::Server>(provider, m_connectionHandler);
  server->run(true);
  servers.push_back(server);
}
```